# WiFi is interfering with wireless Logitech VX Revolution mouse

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-mouse

I'd been having trouble with my **Logitech VX Revolution** wireless mouse after about 2 years of ownership.  I figured that, since I use it all the time, it was worn out.  The problem I was having was that the left click would only register about a third of the time.  As I said, I thought I had just worn the mouse out so I bought a new (refurbished, actually) VX Revolution and receiver and I'm still having the same problems.  That caused me to Google this, and apparently, I'm not the only one with these issues.

It seems that my 2.4 GHz wireless is interfering with the mouse, and the higher speeds at which I download, the worse my mouse behaves.  If I disable my wireless card (802.11b/g), I have no problems at all with my mouse.

I've used Logitech's connection utility to re-pair my mouse with the receiver, thinking it might use a different frequency that wouldn't interfere, but it didn't.  Any suggestions?  I've tried to be as specific as I can.  Here are my computer's specs:

- [HP dv6449us laptop](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01072707&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3444107&lang=en)
- Windows 7 x86 RTM (problem occurred on XP x86 and Ubuntu x86 as well)
- Logitech VX Revolution with included receiver and with smaller Nano receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, sorry for answering my own question again, but I figured out the problem and I hope this helps others.  I had been using the Broadcom wireless driver that installed with Windows 7.  I rolled back to an old driver (5.10.38.26) and since then I've had no problem with my wireless mouse at all.  Now, as I'm writing this, I'm sitting in a campus lounge, and there is a girl with a laptop that is nearly (or exactly, I don't know for sure) the same model as mine.  Suddenly, my wireless mouse is screwing up again.  I'd wager that she is running the newer driver that Windows Update provides, and it is messing with my wireless mouse.

Hope this info helps anyone who has like problems.

Comment: interesting since you said the problem existed on XP and Ubuntu as well.
Suspect something about the driver is different if this is indeed th e thing which fixes it (eg polling for networks, power saving)

Comment: I know.  I'm a junkie for the newest software, driver, and firmware versions.  Get ready for the cliche: I guess newer isn't always better (ie: Han shot first :))

Answer (score 7):

Tricky, since the Logitech seems to be using a proprietary radio protocol, I think. If it was Bluetooth I would not expect this type of interference since that uses the whole of the 2.4 GHz band, changing frequency 1600 times a second so it is only ever on one particular frequency for a very tiny fraction of the time.

My guess is that the Logitech is using one or one of a very small number of narrow-band frequencies, and this happens to fall within range of your wi-fi signal. A more reliable way to beat the interference would be to change your wi-fi access point (or router with built-in AP) to a different channel, as far away from the current one as possible (eg go from 1 to 11, or vice versa).

Comment: How do I change the channel for my wireless card?

Comment: You need to connect to your access point or router, probably using a browser unless it is a reall old school one, and in the wireless settings you should be able to choose a channel from 1 to 11 (or 1 to 13 in Europe). Only channels with at least 4 other channels in between have no overlap of sidebands, so traditionally people use 1,6, and 11 or 1,7 and 13 in Europe/UK to avoid interference with other local networks.
Of course, you might also want to use something like "wireless net view" from www.nirsoft.net to see if the interference might be from someone else's wifi as well

Comment: @Niphoet: wifi channel is set on the AP/router, not on the wireless card.  if you don't have access to the network's configuration you won't be able to change this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a router that is able to set the "Preamble Mode" between "Long Preamble" and "Short Preamble". Please, set it to "Long Preamble"...

I had the same problem with the Logitech Performance MX Cordless Laser Mouse. It interfers with my Netgear Dual Band Router on the 2.4Ghz Band...

Since I set my Preamble Mode to Long Preamble, problem solved...

That is my 2 cents..

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

I've had a weird problem with a Belkin USB wireless adapter misbehaving for a few days, and at times when trying to fix things by rearranging USB ports, sometimes the wireless keyboard/mouse set got really sluggish. After googling a bit I found this thread and on a theory, I just moved the keyboard/mouse receiver to a port on the front of the desktop and left the Belkin in a port at the back of the desktop, and voila! Both problems resolved. It seems that proximity problems in WiFi might be a matter of inches between devices.

Answer (score 0):

As AdamV suggested, you should experiment with different channels on your AP.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to make a choice:  your wireless mouse, or your wireless network?  Replacing one of them with the wired equivalent will definitely take care of any interference issues.

You might also look into a proper bluetooth mouse, but that can also run into issues co-existing with wireless.

Answer (score 0):

I dug out my USB wireless adapter and am using it on the same laptop, same network, and with the same mouse and it seems to work fine, even at very fast download speeds.  Maybe something about the Broadcom card in my laptop doesn't play nice with my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that Wifi would interfere with it.  I had the same issue on my system.  I eventually deduced that there was too much noise around my computer and the device was a bit far from it (as my PC is on the floor).

So, I used a USB extension cable to bring the dongle closer to my mouse.  Its never missed a beat since then.