# Wireless mouse keeps freezing when using whole network bandwidth

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse, freeze, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

Hi i have wireless mouse and keyboard connected to pc with USB receiver.
When i downloading something without limiting download speed, mouse and keyboard keep freezing randomly.

```
Mouse           : Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000
Keyboard        : Microsoft keyboard 3000 v2
Chipset         : Intel HM65
Processor       : Intel Core i7 2670QM @ 2200MHz
Physical Memory : 8192MB (2 x 4096 DDR3-SDRAM)
OS              : Win Ultimate 7 x64
```

Note : The solution described in https://superuser.com/a/309622/157168 not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless mouse and keyboard, while using the same frequency as two of the wireless standards, isn't using the same protocol. [Interference is a possibility](https://superuser.com/questions/67956/wifi-is-interfering-with-wireless-logitech-vx-revolution-mouse) if you're using wireless - though your question is lacking information on how you're connected to the internet.

While MS [claims its unlikely](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/3/2/3324D913-59F5-4EA2-BC6E-AA6EDBECFB9D/Microsoft_Wireless_Comparison_vs_27Mhz.pdf&ei=9weVUP_ZBo-HrAeo54D4Ag&usg=AFQjCNFh5A2RFKfasMLwZEfzZATn8cOnYw&sig2=sj2fJGCxi50VjemljPDtDg&cad=rja) there's reports of it on their own [support site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/wireless-keyboard-mouse-issues/c6300ed3-aced-4af0-9112-9756e269fef4). Their troubleshooting hints seem a little useless though - here's a google cache cause their [site is down](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gFS_aGM_tYMJ:support.microsoft.com/kb/322609%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk)

On the short run, try switching to wired net or keyboard/mouse to see if there's still an issue. Try switching wifi channels to see if that helps too.

Comment: That little useless things worked :) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to make a guess I would say that you're using a USB network card. When you download at the full rate it might be blocking your keyboard and mouse from communicating with the computer as well.

Try to use an Ethernet connection to your computer and see if that helps the problem.